# add_patch in boxplot with matplotlib (python)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I was doing a custom boxplot mixed with heatmap and found a weird thing in my matplotlib. When adding the patch (ax.add_patch) the patch rect give different vertices when using rect.get_verts().

The idea is to split vertically my boxplot in order to add a color inside the IQR, i.e. IQR goes from [2,6], each unity, ([3,4[;[4,5[;[5,6[) will have a color based on other variable.

[image: boxplot mixed with heatmap]

I thought the easiest way was to get the patch representing the box, get the vertices, divide the height by the number of the units and then create each patch to draw it.

Before adding the rect

```
Patch [[ 610.2 1684.8]
 [ 610.7 1684.8]
 [ 610.7 1685.8]
 [ 610.2 1685.8]
 [ 610.2 1684.8]]
```

After adding the rect

```
Patch [[408697.92  549568.368]
 [409032.72  549568.368]
 [409032.72  549894.528]
 [408697.92  549894.528]
 [408697.92  549568.368]]
```

The graph is therefore meaningless as the tickers are all to the left, the y (which lays between 0,80) goes all the way to 2000.

[image: Wrong graph generated]

This is my current approach:

```
bplot = ax.bxp(y,patch_artist=True)

for patch,q1,q3,label in zip(bplot['boxes'] data_box["q1"],data_box["q3"],data_box["label"]):
    print(f"Label {label}")

    verts = patch.get_verts().copy()
    print(f"Verts : {verts}")
    height = (verts[3] - verts[0]).sum()
    width = (verts[1] - verts[0]).sum()


 
    height_per_unit = height/(q3-q1)

    initial_verts = verts[0].copy()
    for i in range(int(q3-q1)):
        
        rect = patches.Rectangle((initial_verts[0],initial_verts[1]),0.5, 1)
        rectangles.append(rect)
        print(f"Patch {rect.get_verts()}\n" )
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        initial_verts = rect.get_verts()[3]
```

Does anyone knows how to counter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. We need to account for the transformations before and after using `ax.transAxes.inversed().transform()` , ie.

```
for patch,color,q1,q3,label in zip(bplot['boxes'],data_box['Color'], data_box["q1"],data_box["q3"],data_box["label"]):
    # print(f"Label {label}")

    verts = patch.get_verts().copy()

    # WE USE HERE FIRST
    verts = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(verts) 

    print(f"Verts : {verts}")
    height = (verts[3] - verts[0]).sum()
    width = (verts[1] - verts[0]).sum()

    # print(f"Height : {height}\nWidth:{width}")
    
    height_per_unit = height/(q3-q1)
    # print(f"Height per unit : {height_per_unit}")7
    
    initial_verts = verts[0].copy()
    print(initial_verts)
    
    
    for i in range(int(q3-q1)):
       
        rect = patches.Rectangle((initial_verts[0],initial_verts[1]),0.5, 1, zorder=1000)
        rectangles.append(rect)
        
        print(f"Patch {rect.get_verts()}\n" )
        ax.add_patch(rect)

        # THEN WE USE HERE
        initial_verts = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(rect.get_verts())[3]
```